# Переключение классов в vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Пытаюсь разобраться в [vue.js](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html). Есть простой список:

```
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="#" class="link">item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="#" class="link" v-on:click="toggle">item 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Нужно при клике на ссылку присваивать только этому пункту активный класс (т.е. у других пунктов - убирать активность).

С jquery я бы сделала так:

```js
$('.link').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var $this = $(this),
      item = $this.closest('.item');
  
  if(!item.hasClass('active')){
    item.addClass('active')
      .siblings()
      .removeClass('active');
    
  } else {
    item.removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>

  
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="#" class="link">item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="#" class="link" v-on:click="toggle">item 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Вопрос:** как можно реализовать подобное переключение классов с помощью vue (**присвоение класса** не ссылке, а **пункту** `li` -шке)?

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    
  },
  
  methods: {
    toggle: function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      
      alert('click');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>

  
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="#" class="link">item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="#" class="link" v-on:click="toggle">item 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Могу предложить такой вариант:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    activeLink: undefined
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>

  
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li class="item" v-bind:class="{active: activeLink === 1}">
      <a href="#" id='item1' v-on:click.prevent="activeLink = 1">item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item" v-bind:class="{active: activeLink === 2}">
      <a href="#" id='item1'  v-on:click.prevent="activeLink = 2">item 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: я прошу прощения, но задача была не ссылке, а пункту задавать смену класса (при клике на ссылку) `item.addClass('active')
      .siblings()
      .removeClass('active');`

Comment: Ну, ничего не мешает присвоение класса active повесить на элемент li. (Поправил в примере выше). Теперь все работает как Вы хотели?

Comment: все равно не то, если изначально задать "item active", то класс не исчезает при клике ... но спасибо, может кому-то и такой ответ пригодится

Comment: @HamSter В VUE другой подход к классам: Изначально задать "item active" = изначально задать activeLink=ItemNumber в данном случае. Вы либо задаете класс статично, и прописываете его в class="item", и далее его не меняете. Либо привязываете класс к переменной: v-bind:class="{active: isActive}". И тогда наличие/отсутствие класса задается значением переменной!

Answer (score 3):

```
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li class="item" v-bind:class="{active: links.item1}">
      <a href="#" id='item1' v-on:click="toggle">item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item" v-bind:class="{active: links.item2}">
      <a href="#" id='item2' v-on:click="toggle">item 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
     links: {}

  },

  methods: {
     toggle: function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var id = e.target.id;

       this.links = {};
       this.links[id] = true;
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: я прошу прощения, но задача была не ссылке, а пункту задавать смену класса (при клике на ссылку) `item.addClass('active') .siblings() .removeClass('active');`

Comment: и что-то Ваш пример вообще не работает? видимо из-за строки - `var id = $(this).id();`

Comment: это не заработает из-за https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: Пример подправил, он работает, я проверял

Answer (score 1):

Vue действительно предполагает немного другой формат общения между отдельными компонентами, вместо прямой работы с чем-то Vue предлагает изменять данные, а в ответ на изменения Vue будет пересобирать HTML в соответствии с текущим состоянием. Если использовать текущий шаблон, то приведенный @АлексейМатвеев ответ будет самым верным, но скорее всего этот список должен генерироваться "на лету". В этом случае можно было бы сделать так:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function () {
    return {
      activeItem: null,
      items: ['Link 1', 'Link 2']
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.active:after {
  content: '< active';
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.4/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li class="item" v-for="(item, index) in items">
      <a
          href="#" 
          v-bind:class="{link: true, active: activeItem === index}" 
          v-bind:key="index"
          v-on:click.prevent="activeItem = index">
        {{ item }}
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

В этом случае список создается из data.items, а по клику на элемент data.activeItem устанавливается равным индексу текущего элемента. Директива v-bind:class анализирует объект и устанавливает классами те ключи, для которы значение составляет true. Таким образом класс active автоматом будет устанавливаться только для тех элементов, у которых индекс совпадает с activeItem (такой элемент, конечно, только один). Если бы нужно было  выделить какой-то элемент по умолчанию, достаточно было бы установить activeItem в соответствующий индекс с самого начала (например, в 0).

В более сложном примере отдельные элементы списка были бы отдельными компонентами и не имели бы общей data. В этом случае компонент должен был бы по клику создавать событие (toggle), а родительский элемент ловить его и менять data, activeItem из которой передавался бы в дочерние элементы в качестве prop.

Ссылки по теме:

- [Рендеринг списков](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html)
- [Работа с классами и стилями](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)
- [Компоненты (в т.ч. отношения родитель/дочерний компонент)](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html)

Comment: в общем в vue искать аналог jquery не стоит, все совершенно иначе.